# ¿Cómo se puede resolver una Excepción?

Tags: java, exec-maven-plugin

Me encuentro haciendo un proyecto en java con maven en el IDE de netbeans y en el momento de la ejecución del proyecto me salió `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.ClassLoader[] org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.getClassLoaders()'`

Esto es lo que se ejecuta para que me de el error antes mencionado

```
private void btnContinuarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                             
        String cadena = txtArchivo.getText();
        if (cadena.equals("") || !cadena.contains(".xlsx")) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No ha seleccionado un archivo excel para la conversión, seleccione un archivo");
        } else {            
            try {
                String separador = Pattern.quote("\\");
                String[] ruta = cadena.split(separador);
                String finalA = cadena.replace("xlsx", "pdf");
                String nombreHoja = "Hoja1";
                               
                Workbook wb = new Workbook(cadena);                       
                wb.save(finalA,SaveFormat.PDF);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Archivo pdf creado");
                
                int nFila = 6, nColumna = 1;
                Lectura lect = new Lectura();
                String dirCorreo = lect.leerCelda(cadena, nombreHoja, nFila, nColumna);
                                                
                String sujetoC = "Prueba";
                String dirCorreo2 =  "correo_pruebas@yahoo.com";             
                String cuerpoC = "Esta notificación se envio a <" + dirCorreo + ">, si recibió este correo por error notifique a la misma dirección.";
                Configurator.setRootLevel(Level.ERROR);
                EnviarCorreo.enviarCorreoConAdjunto(dirCorreo2, sujetoC, cuerpoC , finalA);                
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(Interfaz.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
```

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.14.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Me gustaría saber si tengo que agregar alguna dependencia en el pom del proyecto o qué se debe modificar para poder cumplir la ejecución de todo el código.

Answer (score 1):

El error "Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'java.lang.ClassLoader[] org.apache.logging.log4j.util.LoaderUtil.getClassLoaders()'" se produce cuando el método getClassLoaders() de la clase LoaderUtil en la biblioteca Log4j no se encuentra. Esto puede ocurrir si se está utilizando una versión incompatible de Log4j o si hay un conflicto de versiones en el proyecto.

Mi solución fue en el pom poner la última versión de `Log4j` que en el momento es la 2.20.0, luego hacer un `Clean` en el proyecto, poner "Resolver Problemas" cuando se da click derecho en el proyecto (esto hizo que se modifiquen las importaciones), comentar la línea de `Configurator....` y por último compilar para ejecutar nuevamente el proyecto.